# How do I install TazPkg in SliTaz Linux

Tags: slitaz

How do I install TazPkg in [SliTaz Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97494/7453)?

Usually to install tazpkg packages you need TazPkg but I unsintalled TazPkg because it was broken now how do I install it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just download the [TazPkg](http://mirror.slitaz.org/packages/cooking/tazpkg-5.1.tazpkg). The packages are available from the [SliTaz website](http://pkgs.slitaz.org/search.sh?package=taz).

Once you've downloaded this file you can use the following steps to manually unpack its files.

#### Steps

1. Download

   ```
   $ wget http://mirror.slitaz.org/packages/cooking/tazpkg-5.1.tazpkg
   ```
2. uncompress file

   ```
   $ mv tazpkg-5.1.tazpkg tazpkg-5.1.tazpkg.gz
   $ gunzip tazpkg-5.1.tazpkg.gz
   ```
3. cpio extract archive

   ```
   $ cpio -id < tazpkg-5.1.tazpkg
   ```
4. contents of extracted archive

   ```
   $ ls -l
   total 152
   -rw-r--r-- 1 saml saml  1213 Oct 24 22:57 files.list
   -rw-r--r-- 1 saml saml 66044 Oct 24 22:57 fs.cpio.lzma
   -rw-r--r-- 1 saml saml  1958 Oct 24 22:57 md5sum
   -rw-r--r-- 1 saml saml  1648 Oct 24 22:57 receipt
   ```
5. uncopressed .lzma file

   ```
   $ lzcat fs.cpio.lzma | cpio -idm
   596 blocks
   ```
6. resulting extracted files

   ```
   $ find fs/ -ls | head -5
   10895752    4 drwxr-xr-x   4 saml     saml         4096 Oct 24 22:59 fs/
   10895756    4 drwxr-xr-x   4 saml     saml         4096 Oct 24 22:59 fs/usr
   10895757    4 drwxr-xr-x   8 saml     saml         4096 Oct 24 22:59 fs/usr/share
   10895758    4 drwxr-xr-x   3 saml     saml         4096 Oct 24 22:59 fs/usr/share/icons
   10895759    4 drwxr-xr-x   3 saml     saml         4096 Oct 24 22:59 fs/usr/share/icons/hicolor
   ....
   ```

The files in the `fs/` directory can then be moved into position to regain the tool `tazpkg`.

```
$ find fs/|grep "/bin/tazpkg$"
fs/usr/bin/tazpkg
```

#### References

- [How do I use cpio command under Linux?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-use-cpio-command-under-linux/)
- [tazpkg fs.cpio.gz not found... fs.cpio.lzma?](http://vanilla.slitaz.org/index.php?p=/discussion/514/tazpkg-fs.cpio.gz-not-found...-fs.cpio.lzmas/p1)

Comment: @SSpoke - thanks for the Q. You can also upvote this A in addition to the accept 8-).